# Symfony 2 doesn't display field in edit and create forms

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

I have entity **good** with fields: name, cost, description and etc. If I want to create new good or edit, I won't have field **name** in result html. That is in **good** entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;
/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Good
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

**GoodController**:

```
 public function editAction(Request $request, Good $good)
    {
       ...
        $editForm = $this->createForm('Shop\ShopBundle\Form\GoodType', $good);
       ...
  }
```

Create action has sample form. If I try call such code in twig template,

```
{{ form_label(edit_form.name) }}
```

I'll have

> Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "name()",
>   "getname()"/"isname()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in
>   class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

What's wrong?

Comment: I forgot check this class(( There isn't add name in this class, thx for prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing the insctruction of the FormType
for every entity there should be a file `EntityFormType.php`
and there you will add your fields like this

```
    $builder->add('name', null, array(
    'required'   => false,
    'empty_data' => 'John Doe',
    ));
```